# What is the correct way to export an Async function module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I have a file `asyncAwait.js` that has a simple function:

```
async function doStuff() {
    return(`Function returned string.`);
}

module.exports.doStuff = doStuff;
```

In another module, `testing.js`, I invoke and all works as expected:

```
var functions = require(`./functions`);

(async () => {

    const test = await functions.asyncAwait.doStuff();

    console.log(test);

})();
```

This logs "Function returned string." to the console.

All good.

However, if I use axios in `asyncAwait.js`:

```
const axios = require(`axios`);

async function doStuff(parameter) {

    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`;

    const getData = async url => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            const data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return(getData(url));
}

module.exports.doStuff = doStuff;
```

Then in `testing.js`:

```
var functions = require(`./functions`);

(async () => {

    const test = await functions.asyncAwait.doStuff();

    console.log(test);

})();
```

This logs `undefined`.

Why does the function call return undefined in the second example?

Comment: Your `getData()` function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: `getData` is not returning anything

Comment: `console.log(data);` will log the data but `console.log(test);` will log `undefined` because `getData(url)` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In your example `getData` has no return. In this case your function will implicitly return `undefined`. To fix it you could change that function to the following:

```
    const getData = async url => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet - However, still returns `undefined` on export.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.doStuff = doStuff;
```

May I suggest you :

```
module.exports=doStuff;
```

Or

```
exports.doStuff
```

and maybe but not sure what you're trying to achieve 
replace

```
return(getData(url));
```

by

```
return(()=>{return getData(url)});
```